# How to get a list of a single users URL likes with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm writing a php application that, in the back end, gets a list of all the URLs a single user shares and likes.

For shares it's easy and consistent - I run a FQL query request that looks like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url,+title+FROM+link+WHERE+owner=me()

However, I would also like a list of URLs that a user "likes" by clicking the "Like" button on a page. I used to be able to do this with the following query:

graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url+FROM+url_like+WHERE+user_id=me()

However, this seems to only give back the URLs that I liked within facebook by clicking "like". What I am looking for, is obtaining a list of URLs I liked by clicking the "like" button on its page. I am fairly use the url_like table used to give you that functionality, but not anymore

For example - the following link (used only as an example) has a like button - http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2013/sep/24/injustice-gods-among-us-106-balance-patch-notes-full-list/ 
I clicked the "like" button. It is now greyed out. However I can't find any evidence of this using FQL.

I am trying to figure out a way to see the links a user "liked" by pressing the button. 
Thanks in advance